# ASP.NET session mixing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

We have our ASP.NET sessions persisted to a central SQL server. So now all session data is forced to travel over the wire to an SQL server, even if it's just trivial information. Can I mix sessions --- ie. Keep SQL for session["abc"] = "value" and have an overwrite to store stuff locally, such as session.AddLocalMemory["xyz"] = "blah".

Answer (score 3):

Not with any of the built-in providers. You could add an extension method to HttpSession and use it to store stuff locally. This could be done by simply inserting a state bag into ASP .NET memory cache with a timeout.

If this is a load balanced environment (involving more than one web server), you should consider the consequences of different requests going to different servers, and use local storage accordingly.

Comment: Agree. To add another point to be careful: Loosing local session data is not limited to load balanced environment, but also regularly caused by process recycles. Another thing to consider if such mixing would be clear to future developers of the system - and how painfull moving from local to SQL storage for particular pieces would be (SQL/out of process state requires objects to be serializable, which is often not the case for things you drop to local state...)